# Datadog APM: MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected

Tags: node.js, socket.io, datadog

Working on a datadog apm integration with NodeJS based server.

We use an API template for building a new API, and that template has a default integration with DD. It takes care of tracing all http/express calls.

The server also supports socket connections and these connections are not being traced by that default tracer. So I had to write a custom tracing logic to trace those actions. However that requires me to re-import dd-trace library and run .init() on it.

Everything seems to work fine, however I noticed in the server logs there are 2 or 3 log entries like these

> MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 connect listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit

If I remove the custom tracing, then sometimes I get one or none of these. So these do look like they are connected to the init() calls.

I can't re-use the tracer that's initialized in the template as it's not exported from there.

Anyone else has had a similar issue? Any suggestions on how to resolve it?

node: v14
dd-trace: v3.17.1

If I remove the second init() call, then the traces are not sent (as expected).

Comment: I think the best way to fix this is to use something like dependency injection such that the API endpoints can configure the tracer to some degree. That said, in this case, you can estimate the number of sockets and therefore the number of Event Listeners, and you may be able to safely increase the limit after looking at resources and usage.